# What is the best way for the layout to extract data from a page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Basically, I have a page that references a layout page acting as a template "window" container. What I want to know is what is the best (Non-`ViewBag`) method to pass information from the inner page, to the layout page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind the template to a View Model. It's best to have a base View Model (for the parent) and then your child View Model will implement the parent View Model.

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
      public string SomeSharedField { get; set; }
}

public class ChildViewModel : ParentViewModel
{
      public string SomeFieldJustForChild { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Works like the charm. Ty sir!